# Understanding Next.JS with-iron-sessions requirements for use in own environment

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to get some of the examples located in the with-ireon-sessions github account to work with my own back-end: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-iron-session

I can sign in using `const { user, mutateUser } = useUser();` with `useUser()` being from the example: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-iron-session/lib/useUser.js

My sign-in method looks like this;

```
const signIn = async ({ email, password, remember_me }) => {
    try {
      await mutateUser(
        fetchJson(`${API.baseURL}/${API.signIn}`, {
          method: "POST",
          headers: { 
            "Accept": 'application/json',
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            email,
            password
          })
        })
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("An unexpected error happened:", error);
      setErrorMessage((<p className="error">{error.data.message}</p>));
    }
};
```

I can see my user change, but I still have the following issues:

1. I don't see any cookies get created. Does with-iron-sessions require the site to be deployed to the vercel cloud in order for cookies to get added, or am I right in thinking I can use my own server and API endpoints?
2. What's the pattern for using the `/api/user` endpoint in [useUser.js](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-iron-session/lib/useUser.js); does the endpoint look for the cookies (that are not getting created for me) and do it's own validation, or is there validation I need to do in my version of that endpoint? Is there an example of what that endpoint looks like server-side you might be able to point me to?
3. Is there a way to refresh the cookie (once I get them to appear) so they are X days since *last* using the site instead of X days from *first* login so it's a sliding cookie lifespan, or does that happen automatically?
4. When I sign out my sign_out endpoint returns a 204 status code but the UI doesn't change like it does when I sign in. Any tips for me there?
   Thank you!

Comment: Regarding the second point, `/api/user` endpoint is handled by the [file in `pages/api/user`](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-iron-session/pages/api/user.js).